# Unable to display Interstitial ads on button click

Tags: android, admob, ads

There are 10 buttons and each button from the activity navigates to a new activity. I've written a code to display an Interstitial ad every time when a button is clicked.
But it doesn't show the ad always when it is clicked.

May I know where I'm going wrong in the code?

Code -

```
public class home_activity extends AppCompatActivity implements ConnectivityReceiver.ConnectivityReceiverListener {


    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;    
    private static final String TAG = "home_activity";
    private AdView mAdView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-4189677300263650/4868306863");
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            }
        });

        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
        public void motorcycle_btn(View view) {
        //If loaded show ad
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        } else {
            //Even if Ad is not loaded show the Second Activity
            startActivity(new Intent(home_activity.this, CC_motorcycle.class));
        }
    }

    public void privatecar_btn(View view) {
        //If loaded show ad
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        } else {
            //Even if Ad is not loaded show the Second Activity
            startActivity(new Intent(home_activity.this, CC_car.class));
        }
    }

    public void taxi_upto6_btn(View view) {
        //If loaded show ad
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        } else {
            //Even if Ad is not loaded show the Second Activity
            startActivity(new Intent(home_activity.this, CC_motorcycle.class));
        }
    }

    public void bus_btn(View view) {
        //If loaded show ad
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        } else {
            //Even if Ad is not loaded show the Second Activity
            startActivity(new Intent(home_activity.this, CC_bus.class));
        }
    }

    public void passauto_btn(View view) {
        //If loaded show ad
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        } else {
            //Even if Ad is not loaded show the Second Activity
            startActivity(new Intent(home_activity.this, CC_passauto.class));
        }
    }

    public void goodsauto_public_btn(View view) {
        //If loaded show ad
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        } else {
            //Even if Ad is not loaded show the Second Activity
            startActivity(new Intent(home_activity.this, pt_goodsauto_public.class));
        }
    }

    public void goodsauto_private_btn(View view) {
        //If loaded show ad
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        } else {
            //Even if Ad is not loaded show the Second Activity
            startActivity(new Intent(home_activity.this, pt_goodsauto_private.class));
        }
    }

    public void commercialvehiclepublic_btn(View view) {
        //If loaded show ad
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        } else {
            //Even if Ad is not loaded show the Second Activity
            startActivity(new Intent(home_activity.this, CC_commercialvehiclepublic.class));
        }
    }

    public void commercialvehicleprivate_btn(View view) {
        //If loaded show ad
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        } else {
            //Even if Ad is not loaded show the Second Activity
            startActivity(new Intent(home_activity.this, CC_commercialvehicleprivate.class));
        }
    }

    public void agri_btn(View view) {
        //If loaded show ad
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        } else {
            //Even if Ad is not loaded show the Second Activity
            startActivity(new Intent(home_activity.this, pt_agri.class));
        }
    }
}
```

P.S - I'm trying to implement Banner as well as Interstitial ads in the project.
Banner ad is working fine but it takes some time to display after the activity is loaded.

Comment: are you checking on emulator or real device?

Comment: Real device @Munir

Comment: It's probably because the interstitial is not ready to be shown. So the isLoaded() if statement follows the else path.

Comment: It display the ads sometimes when I navigate to the second activity on button click and return back to the home activity @RabRoss

Comment: try to addTestDevice("DEVICE_ID") in adreuest

Comment: Have tried that also @Munir It display the ads sometimes when I navigate to the second activity on button click and return back to the home activity

Comment: You are loading an ad everytime an ad is closed and maybe you are testing before even the second ad is loaded, can you wait for some time before clicking each of the buttons.

Comment: I used TestDevice now the ads are being displayed on button click and remains in the same activity. But I want that to navigate.
Haven't done any changes to the above code @Munir

Comment: I used TestDevice now the ads are being displayed on button click and remains in the same activity. But I want that to navigate.
Haven't done any changes to the above code @RishabhDugar

Comment: I used TestDevice now the ads are being displayed on button click and remains in the same activity. But I want that to navigate.
Haven't done any changes to the above code @RabRoss

Comment: @AbhishekD write new activity start code in onAdClosed method

Comment: But I've 10 activities. How do I initialize them separately? @Munir

Comment: @AbhishekD keep some track of button, which button is click and according them put condition and according that navigate

Comment: Will do that @Munir

Answer (score 0):

You code for displaying interstitial ad is just fine. Check for these things:

1. Have you intialized MobileAds. Code for doing so is

`MobileAds.initialize(this, "YOUR_ADMOB_APP_ID");`

2. Listen for AdLoadFailure.
3. If you just created ad unit it might take a while to display the actual ad, so try using test ads or register test device.

Comment: I used TestDevice now the ads are being displayed on button click and remains in the same activity. But I want that to navigate.
Haven't done any changes to the above code

Comment: for that you have to write `startActivity` code inside call back `onAdClosed`

Comment: But I've 10 activities. How do I initialize them separately?

Answer (score 0):

To load  interstitial ads you need working internet connection.Make sure internet is on.Also you should use testing APP PUBLISHER ID for developement purpose.Not use your production APP PUBLISHER ID.

And For initialize separately you store current button id in variable on button click.And Switch case in OnAdClosed() to match particular activity to open.

Comment: Internet is working, I'm able to get Banner ads but I'm facing difficulties with Interstitial ads!

Comment: use testing publisher id for development